# C++ Assigning Vector to an Array

Tags: c++, arrays, syntax, stdvector

Why is my size changing when assigning a vector to an array?

```
cout << endl << vertices.size() << endl;  //outputs correct number-> 89473
GLfloat* Vertices = &vertices[0];
GLfloat* Colors = &colors[0];
cout << endl << sizeof(Vertices) << endl; //outputs incorrect number-> 4
```

I know I can just loop through and assign individually (as opposed to one line of assignment), but I just want to know why this is happening.

Comment: `Vertices` is a pointer. You are looking at the size of a pointer on your platform. That is `4`.

Comment: And just to be completely clear, pointers (any type ending with a `*`) do not store size or dimension information regarding what they point to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vertices.size()` gives the number of elements in the vertices array (89473) while `sizeof(Vertices)` calculates the size of a pointer, which happens to be 4.